# What does an asterisk at the end of a mv command do

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wildcard

So I am going along and moving a bunch of files

```
mv /source /dest &
mv /source/* /dest/dest/ &
...
...
```

then I get careless and

```
mv /source/filena* /dest/dest/ *
```

OMG! `^c^c^c^c`
[No Response from terminal command]
What is actually going on here?

What happens when I put an `*` (asterisk) at the end of a command instead of an `&` (ampersand)?

Comment: Tip: `alias mv='mv -i'` ensures that you have to say ok before clobbering a file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell expands the wildcard `*`. The `mv` command never sees the wildcard, only the result of the expansion.

The wildcard `*` expands to the list of files in the current directory in lexicographic order. If the last file is a directory, then all the preceding files (`/source.filenafoo`, `/source/filenabar`, `/dest/dest`, `hello`) are moved to that subdirectory. If the last file is not a directory, `mv` complains that “target `a.png` is not a directory” (or words to that effect).

See [What does `mv ./*` without specifying destination do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/what-does-mv-without-specifying-destination-do) for more detailed examples.

Answer (score 2):

An asterisk at the end of a command line is treated the same way as an asterisk anywhere else on the line — it's a wildcard that matches zero or more characters.  Specifically, in this instance, the `*` in `mv /source/filena* /dest/dest/ *` is replaced by the name of each & every file and folder in your current directory (except those beginning with a dot), and whatever happens to be last in this list is where `mv` is going to try to put everything.