# How do I accept a literal "*" as a command-line argument?

Tags: shell, rust

I am writing a very simple command line calculator in rust, getting a number ,an operator, then another number and do the calculation and print the result. To show what I am getting from command args, I have printed them in a loop before the main code. I works fine for plus, minus and division, but for multiplication I get unexpected result, as I print it, instead of a star (*) for multiplication, I get the files list on my current directory.
Here is my rust code, I will appreciate an explanation and if there is any workaround.

```
use std::env;

fn main(){
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    for arg in args.iter(){
        println!("{}", arg);
    }

    let mut result = 0;
    let opt = args[2].to_string();
    let oper1 = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let oper2 = args[3].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    match opt.as_ref(){
        "+" => result = oper1 + oper2,
        "-" => result = oper1 - oper2,
        "*" => result = oper1 * oper2,
        "/" => result = oper1 / oper2,
        _ => println!("Error")
    }

    println!("{} {} {} = {}", oper1, opt, oper2, result);

}
```

Comment: Your shell is converting the star. It's not the program. You can wrap it in quotes, such as "*" and it should work (when passing it into the application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wildcard (*) is expanding out. The shell is going to send this out to the program before it even sees what you *actually typed*

[You can read more about here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18325066/1554844)

To avoid this, you can just wrap it in quotes, like so:

```
./program 1 "*" 1
```

Comment: While this does answer the question, I'd rather quote the entire expression and use `./program '1 * 1'` to avoid further surprises.